# I can not get Branch install parameters after opening app from Shared Link in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate, branch.io

I am sharing link with Branch.io , but when I am installing app from the link in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, not getting the Branch parameters.

```
[[Branch getInstance] initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions isReferrable:YES andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary * _Nullable params, NSError * _Nullable error) {
if (!error) {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            // params will be empty if no data found
            // ... insert custom logic here ...
            NSLog(@"branch params.description: %@", params.description);
            NSLog(@"branch params: %@", params);

            

        } else {
            NSLog(@"branch error: %@", error);
        }
    }];


branch params don't have the embedded properties in it, and also it cant detect it is installed from Link.

It always prints:
branch params: {
    "+clicked_branch_link" = 0;
    "+is_first_session" = 0;
}
```

I have set all the key information and associate domains in Project.
[image]

What can be the reason for this, is it related to ios version? or Branch sdk problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if you have configured your API Keys correctly? Make sure if you are using Live API key, then you are clicking on a live link

Comment: hi @KartikShandilya, thanks for the reply. yes, I have the live key setup and in the dashboard also Live configuration is selected. but still found empty param dict

Comment: One thing I noticed that if I copy sharing link, then paste it in Safari browser, after link installation I found param dictionary most of the time, but directly clicking through a link shared in WhatsApp or Skype, param dict is lost in didFinishLaunchWithOptions

Comment: The issue could be with your Universal Link Handler. Can you check if you are overriding this as per docs - https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#initialize-branch?

Comment: Did you figure it out @MMSmmsbd ??

Comment: Sorry @Dasoga. I dont exactly recall if I had found a solution that time. what tends to happen that sometimes I got params, but sometimes dont. It would be helpful if you print out full params dictionary to find out if they (Branch.io) set data in any other fields.